# "The specified procedure could not be found" error when running app on Windows XP (exception c0000139)

Tags: c, windows, dll

We have a dll that has been running fine on Vista and Win7 for a while, but when running on XP we get the error **"The specified procedure could not be found"** when `LoadLibrary()` is called to load it.

I've tried running it through Dependency Walker with the Profile option, with Global Flags set to show loader snaps and the only seemingly useful information I can get out of it is:

```
LDR: Snapping imports for MyDll.dll from KERNEL32.dll
LDR: LdrGetProcedureAddress by NAME - RtlGetLastWin32Error
LDR: exception c0000139 thrown within function LdrpSnapIAT
Exception record: 0012E490
Context record: 0012E4A4
Context->Eip = 7C9673BE
Context->Ebp = 0012E7C0
Context->Esp = 0012E770
LDR: LdrpSnapIAT - caught exception c0000139 snapping thunks (#2)
LDR: LdrpWalkImportTable - LdrpSnapIAT #2 failed with status c0000139
```

I believe that exception `c0000139` is 'Entry Point Not Found'.

We've taken care to ensure that there aren't any direct dependencies on post-XP APIs (there are a few, but these are dynamically loaded with `LoadLibrary()`).  The dll was built with `WINVER` and `_WIN32_WINNT` set to `0x0501`.  The entry point of the library is visible in the exports shown in Dependency Monitor, and there are no obvious missing dependencies.  The same application runs absolutely fine in Vista and Win7.  An earlier version of the dll worked fine on XP (due to the nature of this component it's difficult to see which change caused things to break).

Edit: other things I *think* I've discounted:

- Visual studio runtimes are installed
- The manifest files from a working dll and one that doesn't are the same

Is there anything else obvious I'm missing?

Comment: A totally wild guess: the XP machine doesn't have the required version of the C runtime (CRT) library?

Comment: Yeah, that was my thought, but I've added the CRTs.

Comment: I've just had exactly the same issue today...  I've got a DLL which loads on all flavours of windows except windows XP.  I also tried loader snaps and seen: (1a8.8c4): Unknown exception - code c0000139 (first chance)
LDR: exception c0000139 thrown within function LdrpSnapIAT

Comment: Is this the first time you've tried the DLL on XP with VS2010?  All I've really done is rebuild my project in 2010 (when the DLL used to load when built with 2008)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've no idea if this will help you but I had the exact same issue today with loader snaps.  It turned out that my problem was visible in depends.exe but I didn't know the significance of dlls being pink...  I've only ever diagnosed export issues with depends, not import issues.

My issue was that I was using "RegGetValue" which is only available on Vista+.  Unfortunately there's no proper error reporting if you use a Vista only API on Windows XP.  Depends showed this in the import section like so:

[image]

I notice that your issue was with Kernel32.dll rather than Advapi.dll so check the imports with depends...

Comment: By the way, loader snaps didn't tell me that it was RegGetValue...  It just pinpointed Advapi so I had to rely on depends for the rest...

Comment: Thanks Benj, that was exactly the problem!  I hadn't realised the significance of the pink icons either, but I will commit that to memory. In my case it was `Kernel32.dll`.  My dll was calling some of the functions added in Vista (eg `InitialiseConditionVariable()`).  These couldn't be resolved in `kernel32` when it was loaded which results in the c0000139 exception.

Comment: Great, glad it helped!  I had a feeling it was the same problem.