# Debugging process load exception 0xc0000138 (Ordinal not found)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, dll

[image]while running my VC++ application on VS2010 i am getting following errors:-

```
'26aprilmadefromnewfoldercode.exe': Loaded 'C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\My Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\26aprilmadefromnewfoldercode\Debug\26aprilmadefromnewfoldercode.exe', Symbols loaded.
'26aprilmadefromnewfoldercode.exe': Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\ntdll.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'26aprilmadefromnewfoldercode.exe': Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\kernel32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'26aprilmadefromnewfoldercode.exe': Loaded 'C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\My Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\26aprilmadefromnewfoldercode\Debug\hdpw32.dll', Binary was not built with debug information.
'26aprilmadefromnewfoldercode.exe': Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\winmm.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'26aprilmadefromnewfoldercode.exe': Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\advapi32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'26aprilmadefromnewfoldercode.exe': Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\rpcrt4.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'26aprilmadefromnewfoldercode.exe': Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\secur32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'26aprilmadefromnewfoldercode.exe': Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\gdi32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'26aprilmadefromnewfoldercode.exe': Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\user32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'26aprilmadefromnewfoldercode.exe': Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\comctl32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'26aprilmadefromnewfoldercode.exe': Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\shell32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'26aprilmadefromnewfoldercode.exe': Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\msvcrt.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'26aprilmadefromnewfoldercode.exe': Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\shlwapi.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'26aprilmadefromnewfoldercode.exe': Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\setupapi.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
Debugger:: An unhandled non-continuable exception was thrown during process load
The program '[5800] 26aprilmadefromnewfoldercode.exe: Native' has exited with code -1073741512
```

(0xc0000138).

My exe file is built but it doesn't execute. How can I debug the process load or resolve this error?

Comment: Do you have a stack trace or a dump file?

Comment: sir i am new to VC++ i don't know whats stack trace is..

Comment: @Rup i have put mine all dll in debug folder itself

Comment: Where is your exe being run from ? Is your exe the release build or debug build ?

Comment: @DumbCoder my exe is debug build i run it by opening solution in VS2010 and pressing F5 key

Comment: You won't get a stack trace or a dump from this since it appears to have failed during dynamic library loading.  The best think you can do with this is load it in depends.exe and look at the imported libraries and symbols, this should tell you which one can't be found.

Comment: @Benj oh that kind of ordinal - d'oh, of course :-/ That's almost certainly the answer if you want to post that. I'd guess it's a mismatch between the import library for his hdpw32.dll.

Comment: @Benj i opened my exe in dependency walker i shows a a box filled with red dots infront of following dll:-ADVAPI32.DLL,HDPW32.DLL,KERNEL32.DLL,KERNEL32.DLL
MSVCRT.DLL
NTDLL.DLL
RPCRT4.DLL
SHELL32.DLL
USER32.DLL
DUSER.DLL
MPR.DLL
UXTHEME.DLL

Comment: Some are to be expected, e.g. for IE shims. Double click on them and look at the errors window, and look at the inidividual DLLs in the tree at the top. You're looking for a non-delay-load DLL with missing imports.

Answer (score 3):

You won't get a stack trace or a dump from this since it appears to have failed during dynamic library loading.  The best think you can do with this is load it in depends.exe and look at the imported libraries and symbols, this should tell you which one can't be found.

Take a look at this question:

["The specified procedure could not be found" error when running app on Windows XP (exception c0000139)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8908112/the-specified-procedure-could-not-be-found-error-when-running-app-on-windows-x/8912684#8912684)

It shows what can happen if you attempt to link against an API which is not available at dynamic link time and how to debug it using depends.exe.

Answer (score 3):

I observed the very same `0xC0000138: Ordinal Not Found` exception in a Windows process loading plug-in DLLs. The error was caused by two different versions of **COMCTL32** loaded into the same process.

Try to use debugger (or [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx)) and check if by any chance you don't get two COMCTL32 modules loaded, like here:

```
...
'C:\Windows\winsxs\x86_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_5.82.7601.18201_none_ec80f00e8593ece5\comctl32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
...
'C:\Windows\winsxs\x86_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.7601.17514_none_41e6975e2bd6f2b2\comctl32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
```

If that's the case, then add explicit COMCTL32 reference to your application's manifest:

```
<dependency>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity type="win32" 
      name="Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls" version="6.0.0.0"
      processorArchitecture="x86" publicKeyToken="6595b64144ccf1df" language="*">
    </assemblyIdentity>
  </dependentAssembly>
</dependency>
```

using one of the methods explained in [MSDN: Enabling Visual Styles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773175%28VS.85%29.aspx) article.

Answer (score 1):

It could be happen if you dll's exports the classes and was built with a different version of runtime library. So you have to check if all of your dlls was built with the same compiler with this which you use for your main application build. All you need to do is just clear the solution and build new lib, dlls which will replace the old version you have.

Comment: I know but it must be mentioned and it could be a solution for his problem.

Comment: @Benj i opened my exe in dependency walker i shows a a box filled with red dots infront of following dll:-ADVAPI32.DLL,HDPW32.DLL,KERNEL32.DLL,KERNEL32.DLL MSVCRT.DLL NTDLL.DLL RPCRT4.DLL SHELL32.DLL USER32.DLL DUSER.DLL MPR.DLL UXTHEME.DLL.how do i get a hdpw32.dll for my current version?

Comment: @user1312155 Can you post a screenshot of depends.exe?

Comment: @Benj i have uploaded my screnshot,i have linked the libraries hdpw32.lib and ideatools.lib than also its giving errors.my build is succeeded but when i run my exe it give error to check the application setting

Comment: @user1312155 - Those .lib files are just stubs that you link against at compile time.  The issue you're having is that the DLLs can't be found at run time.  Trying copying them into the current dir you're running from (for a start).

Comment: @Benj thanks sir my issue of hdpw32.dll and ideatools.dll is resolved but now also when i am running my program it gives the same error.my dependency walker tools shows error opening file.The syatem cannot the file specified(2) WER.DLL and  IESHIMS.DLL infront of these dll's.

Comment: @benj sir my exe is build but when i double click on it to start it says application setting is incorrect,review the manifest file for details.

Comment: @user1312155 - Don't worry about wer.dll and ieshims.dll, these are delay load dependencies and depends.exe almost always shows these as errors, typically they don't represent a realy issue.  With regard to the other problem, check the system event log, sometimes dynamic linking issues show up here with greater detail.

Comment: @Benj event log says this:-Build started 4/30/2012 6:09:57 PM.
     1>Project "C:\30aprlwork\zip\fsinet (2)\fsinet\fsinet\fsinet.vcxproj" on node 2 (build target(s)).
     1>InitializeBuildStatus:
         Creating "Release\fsinet.unsuccessfulbuild" because "AlwaysCreate" was specified.
       ClCompile:
         All outputs are up-to-date.
         All outputs are up-to-date.

Comment: @user1312155 - That looks like an event relating to build, you need to look for an event relating to running the program/dynamic linking.

Comment: @user1312155 did you check what I mentioned in my answer?? I had the same problem with you and the solution was to build my libs with a valid runtime library. Also make sure that you have installed the valid runtime libraries in your machine. This one is for vs2008 http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29

Comment: @AlexTheo hey alex sir i am running my solution on VS2010 express

Comment: Then download the redist package for vs2010 http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5555. Recompile all of your libs using vs2010. Make sure that all you libs are compiled with vs2010 even third party libs, I had the same problem with a log4cxx, I linked the old vs2008 compiled libs to my vs 2010 project.

Comment: @AlexTheo can u give me a link how to recompile the libs(redist)???i was not clear with your with your statement "Recompile all of your libs using vs2010. "

Comment: I meant that you need to recompile all the libraries used in your project by using the vs2010. Probably you are using some precompiled by other version of vs lib files. I see this dll:C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\My Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\26aprilmadefromnewfoldercode\Debug\hdpw32.dll. So maybe the lib file of this lib is outputed to some other directory than your main project use, and you are using the old version each time.

Comment: @AlexTheo sir actually my project has to take input from a grabber board and hdpw32.lib file is of that grabber board,how can i get the new version???or compile the library for my visual studio version and find the lib file output(that it is going to some other directory).

Comment: You need to go to the project settings and check the output directory settings of this project. After that go to the main project's settings and check if you are linking the right lib file. If not so you need to override the old file or make some settings in your project to get the valid lib file automatically by changing the output directory settings in hdpw project or libs directory in your main project. Also make sure that your dll is right.

Comment: @AlexTheo i try ed everything possible but wasn't able to run my exe,can u do me favor,can we connect through team viewer software?or can i send u project files...

Comment: Ok send it to me using this email address: alekstheod@gmail.com so I will check it today at the evening.

Comment: @AlexTheo the project is aaprox 130mb,how can i send it through mail??can we have any another alternative?\

Comment: I will finish with my work at 20:00 CET just send me your skype id and we will check it at the evening.

Comment: @AlexTheo i am getting an error RC : fatal error RC1106: invalid option: -ologo, altough i have installed the SDK 7.0,what should i do now?

Comment: i am getting an error RC : fatal error RC1106: invalid option: -ologo, altough i have installed the SDK 7.0,what should i do?